# unable to insert xml string into mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, xml, mysqli

i want to insert below xml string into mysql database

```
<message to='". $groupMembersArray[$i] . "@crossmessenger.com' type='groupchat' from='$mFrom'><x  xmlns='jabber:x:event'><offline/><delivered/><displayed/></x><body>$message</body></message>
```

so for that i have written below code

```
     $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","xyz","abc#123","mydb");


for($i = 0 ; $i < $totalMembers ; $i++){

               $stanzaToInsert = "<message to='". $groupMembersArray[$i] ."@crossmessenger.com' type='groupchat' from='$mFrom'><x xmlns='jabber:x:event'><offline/><delivered/><displayed/></x><body>$message</body></message>";

           $msgSize = strlen($stanzaToInsert);
               $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO ofOffline VALUES ('$groupMembersArray[$i]', $messageID, $creationDate, $msgSize, '$stanzaToInsert')";
           mysqli_query($connection, $insertQuery);
           mysqli_commit($connection);
           echo "record $message inserted in table and commited";

}
```

but nothing is inserting in database. if i replace xml string that means value of `stanzaToInsert` to some simple text, then it is inserting value into database.

```
$insertQuery = "INSERT INTO ofOffline VALUES (
                         $groupMembersArray[$i], 
                         $messageID, 
                         $creationDate,
                         $msgSize,
                        'hard coded string'
                       )";
```

so problem is with xml string.

so can i know "what's wrong with me"?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? if no then check your type of message field.

Comment: @ManishJ: no ,not getting any error. type is "text"

Comment: have you tried addslashes() or mysql_escape_string() ?

Comment: @ManishJ tried mysqli_real_escape_string but not worked

Answer (score 1):

you should use [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) before inserting the value like this

```
$stanzaToInsert = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $stanzaToInsert);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use "N" befor the xml string for inert the xml message like this:--

```
(NULL,N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="yes"?><!--This is a test XML file--><filemeta filetype="Audio"><Comments /><AlbumTitle /><TrackNumber /><ArtistName /><Year /><Genre /><TrackTitle /></filemeta>')
```

Yourcode should be like this:-

```
$insertQuery = "INSERT INTO ofOffline VALUES (
                             $groupMembersArray[$i], 
                             $messageID, 
                             $creationDate,
                             $msgSize,
                            N'$xmlstring'
                           )";
```